# How to create emails for Android so it fits to screen / zooms out / scales like in iOS

Tags: android, html, ios, email, html-email

When an email with width larger than the resolution of iOS is displayed on iOS, it smartly zooms out to show it in one screen.

What can I do with the HTML email so that it does so on Android as well instead of zooming in like Android devices do?

The email is created with inline css and tables to maximize compatibility with things like Outlook and Gmail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Desktops like width to be in % to cover the entire width, and Apple products adjust to that, however Androids need to be in px. So do this:

```
<body style='width:100%; min-width:600px; ' >....</body>
```

Max-widths on mobile devices shouldn't be greater than 600px.

Comment: This did not seem to work for me <body style="background-color:#fffff;width:100%; min-width:600px;" bgcolor="#ffffff" width="100%">

Comment: Update it seems to work for Gmails App for Android but not for Android 4.2 or 2.3